# Import displays Dicom Image differently in mathematica 9 and 10

Tags: front-end, windows, display

Mathematica 9 (windows 10) displays image as:

[image]

mathematica 10.2 (windows 10:) displays image as:

[image]

Here is the source file:

Import["https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/68983831/46405725"]

How to achieve same display as mathematica 9? No code generated above image. Just the file was imported.

Comment: I think we need the actual source image to figure out what might be going wrong here, not just what's displayed.

Comment: @MichaelWitt uploaded source image

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The root cause is probably that the image is a 16 bit gray-value image which needs adjustment before it can be displayed on most standard monitors (which will have 8 bit gray-values).

For some reason this mapping goes differently in Mathematica 9...

```
Import["https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/68983831/46405725"]
```

[image]

... than in Mathematica 10:

[image]

A workaround would be to do the re-scaling yourself using `ImageAdjust` of the data component of the file:

```
Import["https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/68983831/46405725", 
       {"DICOM", "Data"}][[1]] // Image // ImageAdjust
```

[image]

or by simply dividing by 256:

```
Import["https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/68983831/46405725", 
       {"DICOM", "Data"}][[1]] /256. // Image
```

[image]

Comment: Probably you mean dividing by `255.` because channel values for images of type `"Byte"` in *Mathematica* run from `0` to `255`.

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov no, division by 256 is right shifting by 8 bits, and since the dicom image is 16 bit, this scales back to 8 bits.